# Java library to write sql statements?

Tags: java, sql, code-generation

Does exists a java library that can create sql statements?
I'm not in search of something fancy, just something at "string manipulation" level: I just use jdbc (with Preparestatements and Resultsets) but I don't really like to pass huge strings containing SQL code...

What I need is a "simple" Select class (or something similar); in my mind all I really want is to be able to do

```
SQLStatement stat = Select("*").from("table").where("condition and condition").orderby("something");
ResultSet rs = Connection.getResultSet(stat.toString());
/* equals to "select * from table where condition and condition order by something" */
```

Maybe I'm blind, but I cannot find something like that...

Obviously, I want some methods/class able to write `insert`s and `update`s and the other stuff...

I excluded ORMs for two reasons:

1. the db schema it's "old" and I cannot change it, and I'm not sure how can I adapt the ORM to follow our db
2. AFAIK the ORMs needs to change the model (maybe adding a base class, maybe you need to implements an interface) and the model in my project is big, old and grumpy
3. Onestly, I don't really like ORMs: Objects and Set theory just aren't made to be mapped (IMHO)

Comment: why not use an ORM? For there are **[`plenty!!!`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#Java)**

Comment: The reason this doesn't exist is probably two-fold: a.) replacing string concatenation with meaningful method names is not *that* much of a gain and b.) you should not build full selects using string manipulation in the first place (**especially** not the where condition).

Comment: Funny, last week I had the same thought! :)

Comment: Since `SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE` Statements can vary from DB Server you are using. So Its very difficult to use it without a dialect. In Java most common Utility is Hibernate which have all these functions and many more.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I always forget the precise syntax of the statements (I don't go at this level very often) and IDE simply cannot parse strings, so I found syntax problems at running times (Yes I *do* use unittest, but every time I found an error it's always just a typo like "SLECT" or "WERE")

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan where, there is a common subset for this statements; if I really need something particular (recursive selects?) I just come back to custom strings

Comment: @Vito: I understand. I think your goal is just too close to "use a full-scale ORM" (or at least a light-weight one) that you're unlikely to get a pre-built, well-maintained library for this. You *might* have to start your own (be sure to put it on GitHub or something similar so that the effort is not lost ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORM (Object Relational Mapping) library is the clue.

Hibernate is the most mature one.

And the Hibernate-s Criteria API is object - oriented way to create such queries as You wished. [Criteria API doc.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Comment: +1. Hibernate `Criteria` allows you to write queries such as: 

`createCriteria(Stuff.class).add(Restrictions.eq("property", propValue)).addOrder(Order.asc("name")).list();`

Comment: Hmm, I'm skimming the `Criteria` documentation and it *seems* to be what I want... just... why the hell they don't use an API similar to SQL?

Comment: @Vito: they *do* support HQL, which is somewhat similar to SQL, but building criterias programmatically has all the advantages you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SQLBuilder](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/) project. Honestly, I have not used this. Looking at their docs, i think it might suit your requirement.

You can also try to find similar APIs in Sourceforge,Google code etc..

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is most likely what you're looking for. It contains many advanced features, but SQL statements are more straightforward.

Take a look at their site: http://www.hibernate.org/

I'd also recommend skimming through this guide:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Comment: I second this answer. Hibernate might exactly be what you are looking for. It maps all the database tables and relations as Java classes which you can use conveniently by method calls in a std java way instead of including huge chunks of sql code into your program.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you use Java for a native application or for the web.
If you use Java for web you could consider using the [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/).

Easy and has Hibernate included with a really simple implementation (easier when implementing Hibernate yourself).